# How to set expire timeout for redis set key only for the first key save?

Tags: redis

I have case where i need to save values to redis `SET` structure under given key so i am using command from my code in the loop

```
    SADD key value
    EXPIRE KEY 100
```

However, i would like to set expiration time only on first save of the set `key`. 
Is it possible to set expire time only at the moment of first set key creation ?
it is also should be noted that i can use `EXISTS key` call to redis to check if key exist and depending on that set expiration time or not - but this operation is not atomic.

Comment: You can wrap the logic into a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to ensure that it runs atomically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question - no, there isn't such a command.

As you noted, this could be worked around with EXISTS. To address the atomicity (and save on network) requirement you can use a Lua script (see [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval)).

Answer (score 0):

Redis 7.0 has a new option "NX -- Set expiry only when the key has no expiry". So, you could solve the problem with `EXPIRE KEY 100 NX`.

However, that it doesn't matter if you call `EXPIRE KEY 100` 1 or, let's say, 5 times. The key will expire after 100 seconds, thus checking `EXISTS key` is also an option.